# slow query but when split into sub queries and joined it's quicker

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to Access but my sql is ok. I have inherited an Access DB with linked tables to an sql db outputting data to excel through the connection wizard.

I have what on the surface is a very simple query in Access:

```
SELECT c.cp_customer_Id AS UID,
 u.ud_username AS C3,
 v.ud_username AS C1,
 a.ca_n_1 AS N1
FROM ((dbo_customer_profile AS c
 LEFT JOIN dbo_User_Detail AS u ON c.cp_acc_manager_ud_id = u.ud_id)
 LEFT JOIN dbo_User_Detail AS v ON c.cp_sales_rep = v.ud_id)
 LEFT JOIN dbo_customer_ analysis AS a ON c.cp_customer_id = a.ca_customer_id;
```

Running on ~50k records in dbo_customer_profile I found out that this was taking alot longer than expected. 30+ seconds.

Running essentially the same query (slightly different syntax) directly on the sql db runs in less than 1 second.

Can anyone shine a light on why this is happening?

As a test in Access I split into separate quieres and joined them with another:

OnlyC1&C3

```
SELECT c.cp_customer_Id AS UID,
 u.ud_username AS C3,
 v.ud_username AS C1
FROM (dbo_customer_profile AS c
 LEFT JOIN dbo_User_Detail AS u ON c.cp_acc_manager_ud_id = u.ud_id)
 LEFT JOIN dbo_User_Detail AS v ON c.cp_sales_rep = v.ud_id;
```

and

OnlyN1

```
SELECT c.cp_customer_Id AS UID,
 a.ca_n_1 AS N1
FROM dbo_customer_profile AS c
 LEFT JOIN dbo_customer_analysis AS a ON c.cp_customer_id = a.ca_customer_id;
```

then joined them with

```
SELECT [OnlyC1&C3].UID,
 [OnlyC1&C3].C3,
 [OnlyC1&C3].C1,
 OnlyN1.N1
FROM [OnlyC1&C3]
 LEFT JOIN OnlyN1 ON [OnlyC1&C3].UID = OnlyN1.UID;
```

and this method outputs the exact same data as the original but in less than 1 second.

I don't mind splitting everything out but it seems to be a long way around a simple query.

Comment: This is as expected, because for the first version, Access has to retrieve all records from the joined tables to create the joins. Using the split, for each subquery only two tables are joined which is much faster. Alternatively, if you read only, create a view on the server similar to the first version or run it as a pass-through query.

Comment: @Gustav thanks I didnt know about that qwirk in Access. I'll have a look at pass-through querys - much appreciated!